# How would I save a player's purchases to DataStore?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm working on a game with my friend and we have these game upgrades that unlock new stuff, but I'm wondering how I could save them?

My purchase module is set up like this:

```lua
local module = {}

local Upgrades = {
    { id = "idForThing", cash = 20, callback = function(player) 
        -- hi!
    end, unlimitedPurchases = true, purchased = false }
}

module.getUpgrade = function(upgradeID)
    for i, upg in pairs(Upgrades) do
        if upg.id == upgradeID then
            return upg
        else
            continue
        end
    end
    return nil
end

module.getUpgrades = function()
    return Upgrades
end

module.purchaseUpgrade = function(player, upgradeID)
    for i, upg in pairs(Upgrades) do
        if upg.id == upgradeID then
            if upg.purchased then
                SFX.Error:Play()
                break
            end
            if game:GetService("ServerStorage").Cash.Value >= upg.cash then
                game:GetService("ServerStorage").Cash.Value -= upg.cash
                upg.purchased = not upg.unlimitedPurchases
                upg.callback(player)
                SFX.Purchased:Play()
            else
                SFX.Error:Play()
            end
            break
        else
            continue
        end
    end
end

return module
```

So, basically in the Upgrades table it has items that contain 5 values.

- id

The item ID

- cash

The amount it costs

- callback

Code that runs when purchased

- unlimitedPurchases

If it's true, you can purchase said item more than once

- purchased

Changes to `true` when the player purchases the item.

I made `module.getUpgrades` in hopes that I could just copy the Upgrades table to the DataStore but then it'd also copy the cash which I don't want. I just want it to copy the id and purchased value. So how would I copy just the id and purchased value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the id value and purchased value like this.

```lua
-- for returning single upgrade
module.getUpgrade = function(upgradeID)
    for i, upg in pairs(Upgrades) do
        if upg.id == upgradeID then
            return {id = upg.id, purchased = upg.purchased}
        else
            continue
        end
    end
    return nil
end
-- for multiple upgrades just loop through the table
module.getUpgrades = function()
    res = {}
    for i, v in pairs(Upgrades)do
       table.insert(res,{id = v.id, purchased = v.purchased})
    end
    return res
end
```

If you know what you are doing, you can ignore the rest of my answer.

You need to call the moduleName.getUpgrades() for saving.

```lua
local moduleName = require("YourModuleName")

-- To save, just call the function inside the setAsync
PlayerSavesU:SetAsync(player.UserId, moduleName.getUpgrades())

-- To use the retrieved data from GetAsync();
local data = PlayerSavesU:GetAsync(player.UserId);
if(data ~= nil) then
    for i,v in pairs(data) do
        print(v.id, v.purchased)
    end
end
```

Although, this code might work. It is still not very useful because it does not know which player purchased the items. So you need to add a way to identify each player.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this out. The game is currently single player, not multiplayer so I won't need to identify each player but then again isn't that why I use player.UserId for the save key? lol

Comment: Yes! It works, my players will be super happy! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove keys from a table by setting them to nil `table[key] = nil` (or `table.remove` if you have an array). However there is another catch here that lua tables are passed by reference, so we don't want to remove from the returned value from `getUpgrades` as it'll remove it from the `Upgrades` table as well.

Presuming your `DataStore` has some function `insert(...)` which takes a table and puts it into the datastore; instead what we can do is make a new table with only the keys we want, like:

```lua
local upgrades = module.getUpgrades(id)
local insert_tbl = { id = upgrades.id, purchased = upgrades.purchased }
DataStore.insert(insert_tbl)
```

Comment: Good answer, but the DataStore uses a function called [SetAsync](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/GlobalDataStore/UpdateAsync) to insert data.

Comment: @Kylaaa Thanks, I didn't notice the roblox tag :p. I'll keep it as this bc I'm not sure what key they want but thanks for the info

Comment: Hm it doesn't seem to be working. I have this: `local upgrades = Purchase.getUpgrades() -- new line -- local purchases = { id = upgrades.id, purchased = upgrades.purchased }` and I have it printing upgrades (which returns the upgrades in a table thingy) but purchased returns `{}`.

Comment: `PlayerSavesU:SetAsync(player.UserId, purchases)`